# Apache server + mysql is "hanging" sometimes for several minutes

Tags: mysql, apache

6 employees from 2 locations are using our ticketsystem, that is based on PHP and MySQL. Multiple times a week the employees report that the system doesn't work. The server doesn't respond to none of the users for 1 to 3 minutes. The problem solves automatically. An apache restart doesn't speed this up.

During this time it is still possible to call the apache server status page, but it is not possible to access the database with phpmyadmin.

In Msql (via shell) it is possible to perform "show full processlist" - there are no locks.

We are using Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2l - Server MPM: prefork. mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.60, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3.

The apache server status is showing many W's during the problem - it looks something like this:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWGWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWGGWGWWWWGGWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW______...................
......................

Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process
```

Some configurations:

```
Timeouts: 
    connection: 300    
    keep-alive: 5
MPM Information: 
    Max Daemons: 150 
    Threaded: no 
    Forked: yes

StartServers 5
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 10
MaxRequestWorkers 150
MaxConnectionsPerChild 0

FcgidConnectTimeout 20
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidIOTimeout 600
FcgidMaxRequestLen 314572800
```

There are no entries in the apache error log.

Do you have some ideas where to look or how to find the problem? Do you need more information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be asked on https://serverfault.com/ .. Stackoverflow is for programming questions this question doesn't related to programming

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm asking that question on serverfault.com - thanks for your hint!